# Grep Whitespace across multiple lines

Tags: regex, grep

Given the following in a bunch of text files (.vb):

```
Partial Class [A-Za-z0-9_]
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
```

I'm trying to grep for files that have this basically empty code file, to generate a list of these files, and delete them.

```
grep "Inherits System.Web.UI.Page[:space:]*End Class" -r
```

However the above grep doesn't work... And after reading through the POSIX character classes and grep man pages, I'm stumped

Answer (score 2):

By default, `grep` matches only single lines. But you can use the `-z` (`--null-data`) option to force it to treat the input as a set of null-terminated lines (well, technically to *expect* a set of null-terminated lines, but we provide a non-null-terminated set, therefore treating it as a multiline grep):

```
grep -Pzo -r "Inherits System.Web.UI.Page(\s|\n)*End Class" *
```

Another option is using the `pcregrep` with the `-M` option, like this:

```
pcregrep -M 'Inherits System.Web.UI.Page(\n|\s)*End Class'
```

Comment: grep always treats the input as a set of lines. Here's the full quote from the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html): "Treat  the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline." So, `-z` makes it treat the input as a set of null-terminated lines rather than newline-terminated lines.

Comment: @clacke  Well duh!  That is the point,  as text files generally have no NUL chars, the WHOLE file is read in then searched as a single entity.

Comment: You're both correct. I have reworded my answer to try to make it more clear.